# difference between integer*4 and int32 when using fread in matlab

Tags: matlab, fwrite

I want to read a file with my matlab.The first 200 byte of this file is unnecessary so i put it away and for the rest, i should read 4 byte, 4 byte .because of this, i write a simple code such as below:

```
[fidr, message]= fopen('myfile.format','r' , 'n');
extra=fread(fidr,200,'int8');
fidTemp = fopen('mynewfile.format','w');
while ~feof(fidr)     
Tempc=fread(fidr,1,'int32');    
fwrite(fidTemp , Tempc, 'integer*4');     
Temp_c=Temp_c+1;          
end
[fidr11 , message11] = fopen('mynewfile.format');
mynewfile=fread(fidr11,'int32');
```

when i read matlab help for fread and fwrite i notice for signed 32 bit (4 byte) they mentioned int32 and integer*4 but did not not say what is their differences.is there any difference between them or they are same?

Comment: I dont think there is  a difference. Its just another way of doing it. You can test it. Write 2 files with the 2 options.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you,i check it and it seems that they are same but still i cant understand the benefit of defining 2 same things by matlab.

Comment: One of the most likely reason is legacy. Maybe in older versions of Matlab integer*4 was used and even if they added clearer definitions now the old ones still apply. I am not sure about this thoug, maybe someone knows more than me

Comment: Yeah, it's either legacy or making Fortran users happy since `integer*` and `real*` are old precision declaration forms from that language.

Comment: It's a Fortran/C legacy issue.